# jqTouch UIWebView Tap-Jump Problem

Tags: iphone, uiwebview, jqtouch

I'm using jqTouch inside a UIWebView of my native iPhone application and many of the pages have very weird "tap-jump" issues.

About 75% of the time that I access a page if I scroll down a bit, and just tap anywhere on the screen, it jumps to the top of the page.  If I open that same page in the iPhone Safari browser, it works great every time and no "tap-jump" issue.  So it appears to be an issue ONLY within the UIWebView.

I've been spending hours and hours trying different things to figure out why this is happening and I welcome any ideas.

Thanks,

John

Answer (score 0):

It is expected behavior for jQTouch to scrollTo(0,0) on slide left/right navigation. Of course, this will only create a noticeable effect if you tap a link while the page is scrolled (i.e., if the page isn't scrolled, it can't jump).

I don't know why you'd see a difference between UIWebView and Mobile Safari, unless perhaps the UIWebView is shorter than Mobile Safari, which could create the possibility of scrolling in the UIWebView that doesn't exist in Mobile Safari.

My suggestions are:

- Make sure you have the latest version of jQTouch (https://github.com/senchalabs/jQTouch)
- Make sure you are doing *exactly* the same testing in UIWebView as you are in Mobile Safari (i.e., if you scroll down prior to tapping in one, do the same in the other).

HTH,

j

Comment: Jonathan, thanks for the suggestions and all the work you do on jqTouch. I am using the latest version of jqTouch (I was happy to see some updates a few days ago...hoping that would fix my problems, but alas it did not).  Here is a video of me showing you how it doesn't work in the UIWebView, but does work in Safari. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hjIiY-j1LLo - Very strange :-/.  If you want to view the page I can send it to you, but I can't post it public at this point. Thanks again. John